# How to inject a resolve into a directive with Angular UI-Router State?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in the following format to load a directive. the controller is not specified in the state but inside the directive itself.

```
.state('app.main', {
           url: '/main',
            template: '<my-directive>',
            data: {
              dataName1: 'dataVal1',
              dataName2: 'dataVal2',
            }
})
```

this works well for most cases. however, I am not able to inject a resolve to the directive this way. I have tried the following but keep getting a 'unknown provider' error inside the directive.

```
.state('app.main', {
           resolve: {
              simpleObj: function () {
                return { value: 'simple!' };
              }
            },
           url: '/main',
            template: '<my-directive>',
            data: {
              dataName1: 'dataVal1',
              dataName2: 'dataVal2',
            }
})
```

Is there a way to make the resolve work with this scenerio?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code:

```
resolve: {
     demoResolve: ['myResolvingService', function(resolver) {
          resolver.myValue = 'Foo';
          return '`enter code here`Foo';
     }]
```